# Scripting git commands in Python without external library

Tags: python, git, scripting

I am trying to script a git pull without having to enter a username and password. How would I go about doing this? The only functionality I will be using from git is "git pull".

Comment: You can use ssh keys with git. Don't script sending a password. If you configure key-based auth, you can either use an ssh keyring that you unlock once per login, or just use a key with no passphrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you connecting to the remote git repository?  If you are using an http/https endpoint, read [this document](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Git#Locally_store_your_username.2Fpassword), which includes information about storing your username and password in a `.netrc` file.

You can also embed your username and password in your remote url.

A better choice, if you have the option, is to use `ssh` instead (a remote accessed via ssh looks like `username@somehost.com:/path/to/repo`).  You can then set up ssh key-based authentication, which does not require a username and password.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this is your .git/config:

```
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://<user>:<pass>@github.com/whatever.git
```

for example.

Comment: Do I need to add an identical key if I use this on multiple workstations. I am not concerned about security.

Comment: If you're authenticating with a username and password, then yes, typically you will use the same credentials regardless of where you are connecting from.  On the other hand, if you are using ssh keys you can use a different key at each location (assuming that you are able to control the list of authorized public keys on the remote side).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to run git as an external command.

Comment: I understand that - but how do I pass the command the user name and password so it doesn't prompt? Security is not an issue.

Comment: Set those in your .gitconfig - http://book.git-scm.com/2_setup_and_initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute a command through a shell and interact with it sending input as if it was written from a terminal and getting the subsequent output, then you could use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).